# Conditions and loops withing AngularJS expressions?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, conditional-statements

I have one set of JSON data consisting of the following two objects:

```
{  
   "date":"20160118",
   "entity":"01",
   "security":{  
      "securityID":"191457",
      "identifiers":[  
         {  
            "value":"345342532",
            "type":"fii"
     },
     {  
           "value":"32453452",
           "type":"isin"
     },
     {  
           "value":"48125D886",
           "type":"cusip"
     }
    ]
   }
}
```

And:

```
   {
   "date":"342534543",
   "entity":"01",
   "security":{  
      "securityID":"3425435",
      "identifiers":[  
       {  
          "value":"32543543",
          "type":"fii"
       }
     ]
   }
  }
```

I am creating a table using only AngularJS expressions and HTML.

I'm running into trouble when accessing `security.identifiers[#].value`.  Depending on how many `identifiers` a security has - they may be in different array positions - meaning an "fii" could end up in the same column as a "cusip" for the previous row.  Is there a way within my angular expression I can search through an array and find a string?  In this case `identifiers.type` will be the key to knowing which column it is placed in.  I've tried looping through in my javascript and providing an index to my expression, but I seem to be running into closure issues - I'm hooping there is a simpler way.

So far I have this for my `identifiers` columns - I'm aware they are wrong but hopefully will give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers.type === "fii" ? data.security.identifiers.value : ""}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers.type === "isin" ? data.security.identifiers.value : ""}}</td>
            <td>{{data.security.identifiers.type === "cusip" ? data.security.identifiers.value : ""}}</td>
```

Comment: could you provide full example somewhere on plnk?

Comment: @STEVER https://plnkr.co/edit/OWP8krJBUmZczsqHwyW9?p=preview OK so this is basically where I am now.  As you can see the `cusip` value for row 1 is being displayed in the `fii` column as the array position for `fii` is `0` as there are no other identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand what do you want to do, the below code could work like you expect.

```
<td>{{data.security.identifiers.filter(function(v){return v.type == 'fii'})[0].value}}</td>
```

---

And to improve you can create a function to do the filter (probably in the Controller or Service):

```
$scope.identifierFilter = function(type) {
    var filtered = this.data.security.identifiers.filter(function(v) {
        return v.type == type;
    });
    return filtered && filtered[0] ? filtered[0].value : '';
};
```

and in the html

```
<td>{{identifierFilter('fii')}}</td>
```

---

I'm look at your example, I think the above code would work.But If you can change your JSON structor it will be more better and easy.

```
"identifiers":{
    fii  : 'dfdfdf',
    isin : '32453452',
    cusip: '48125D886'
}
```

html can simple like

```
<td>{{data.security.identifiers.fii}}</td>
```

And if you want to do this transform, I can give you further answer.

with could help

---

**I update your example, sorry about some syntax error about above code.**

please check: **https://plnkr.co/edit/NgvJKrfOGmKHfOap08xU?p=preview**

---

**This is reconstructor data before template use.It's better if the data structor can change, choice which you like.**

**https://plnkr.co/edit/7eHAvSaBcOiTajOomNEs?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm not sure how the first option would work, considering either `fii`, `cusip` or `isin` could be at array position `[0]`, `[1]` or `[2]`?

Comment: It's not use `index` to filter the identifier value, it direct search `type` property.You probably confuse about the `[0]`, it's because the filter method result is an array, and we just want the first object result.You can test it with in your code

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` method api can find in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
It's loop about the array, and find the `type = 'fii'` etc.

Comment: The filter-based solution is clever, but is going to have performance issues (filters are run on every single $digest loop, remember).  Restructuring the data in the controller is a far better solution.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll try that.  I personally couldn't get either of the options above working.

Comment: @DanielBeck That's correct, restructuring the data if it's possible is better solution

Comment: @Jelly I REALLY appreciate your time, and thank you very much for all you possibilities!  I've gotten it to work for part of my code, but some of it relies on a `$q.all` returning a number of promises, so it may be a little hard getting it to work in there, but i have a great starting point.  Again, thanks you :)

Comment: @xeon48 it's my pleasure.And use `Promise` is very convenient in complex situation. Wish you could get better idea in your project :). good night.

Comment: @Jelly - just a little update, I went with your reconstructing data idea and it's working beautifully.  Great answer, thanks again :)

Comment: Very glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your best option is to use a directive, or filter depending on your requirements. A directive will make your mark-up clear and you will encapsulate the functionality you need. For example.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Entity</th>
    <th>SecurityID</th>
    <th>Security1</th>
    <th>Security2</th>
    <th>Security3</th>
    <th>date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in JSONData">
    <td>{{data.entity}}</td>
    <td>{{data.security.securityID}}</td>
    <td><identifier identifiers="data.security.identifiers" render-type="fii"></identifier></td>
    <td><identifier identifiers="data.security.identifiers" render-type="isin"></identifier></td>
    <td><identifier identifiers="data.security.identifiers" render-type="cusip"></identifier></td>
    <td>{{data.date}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6VJuQob1jfDzsR8XPKKM?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , I have accepted Jelly's answer as it is working for now but when I'm back in work tomorrow will certainly take a look through this.

Comment: @Amonn great idea.But it has a limit that when the origin `data` change, the view can't be auto change too.

Comment: Yes, you would have to set the $watch on each data value you want to monitor within the directive, and respond accordingly.